# Recomendation for simple Cortex-M Flash Programmer

Tags: cortex-m

Looking for a recommendation for a simple, inexpensive, flash programmer for the Cortex-M - specifically the nRF51822.

My project is ready to move into the short run prototype stage and I need to program about 10 to 20 units. All the options seem to be either EDU (which I don't qualify for) or $500+. I was hoping for something around the $100 range.

Any recomendations?

Comment: Doesn't seem like shopping question to me.  It's a toolchain question.

Comment: I kind of agree - to me a 'shopping' question would be around where to buy something, not 'what tools are available'. As one of the accepted topics is 'writing of firmware...' how does one discuss the tool chain without making it sound like a shopping question? 

The irony is that the answer given below was right on target and provided me with the answer I needed to move my project forward. If there is another stack exchange site that would cover such discussions, I would gladly move this question there so that other's may find it useful.

Comment: Peek in Area51 for the Embedded Design proposal.  A recent private beta just failed, but a relaunch is being attempted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The nRFgo Development Kit for nRF51822](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nordic-Semiconductor/nRF51822-DK/?qs=7xCC5jQa1OIl3kU93M4e0g==) is only $100, and comes with a Segger J-link Lite which is limited to nRF devices (or maybe a subset of them).

Olimex seems to be the only other viable option I can find.  [THIS](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-JTAG-COOCOX/open-source-hardware) might do the job.  I don't know if it supports nRF parts, but it seems to have plugins for IAR and Keil (though maybe not perfect). [THIS](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7834) is another Olimex product. [this](http://www.coocox.org/forum/topic.php?id=3605) has some info on trying to get Olimex products to work w/ the nRF51822

From all I've read, though, Segger is the way to go.  The base unit, if you don't go with the DevKit option, should run around $350.  That will work only through an IDE, and doesn't include a production programming environment.  For your part count, though, that should be fine, and there's probably free Flash programs w/ Segger plugins, anyway.